# Unzipping files with SSZipArchive - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ssziparchive

I'm trying to unzip a file using the SSZipArchive framework.

```
let unzipper = SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(String(document), toDestination: String(documentsUrl))
```

This is what I'm trying at the moment to unzip the file, and here is the path of the file:

`unzipFileAtPath - Document at path: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/94ADDB12-78A2-4798-856D-0626C41B7AC2/Documents/tSOUTrIayb.zip
false`

And I am trying to unzip it to this path:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, each time there is nothing new being saved into the documents directory which I am printing out. I also print the 'unzipper' variable which just prints `false`, whatever that means.

I can't find any documentation for the framework so I'm not entirely sure how to get this working

Answer (score 7):

Assume that you have implement all things, then also providing solution in few steps

1. Drag `SSZipArchive` folder from the demo which you can download from [here](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive).
2. Write `#import "SSZipArchive.h”` in `yourProjectname-Bridging-Header.h` if you already have. Otherwise create new header file named as mention above.
3. If you want to use delegate methods set delegate to class

   ```
   class YourViewController: UIViewController, SSZipArchiveDelegate {.......
   ```
4. For creating zip form folder I have added sample folder to project (Main bundle)
5. First create folder in document directory where you want to save your zip file

   ```
   var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
   let documentsDir = paths[0]
   let zipPath =  documentsDir.stringByAppendingString("/MyZipFiles") // My folder name in document directory

   let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

   let success = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(zipPath) as Bool

   if success == false {

       do {

           try! fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(zipPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
6. Now create zip file

   ```
   var inputPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
   inputPath = inputPath!.stringByAppendingString("/Sample") // My folder which already put into project

   let archivePath = zipPath.stringByAppendingString(“/Demo.zip") // Sample folder is going to zip with name Demo.zip
   SSZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath(archivePath, withContentsOfDirectory:inputPath)
   ```
7. For unzipping file create folder in document directory (Where you want to save)

   ```
   let destPath = zipPath.stringByAppendingString("/Hello")
   let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

   let success = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destPath) as Bool

   if success == false {

       do {

           try! fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(destPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
8. Unzip folder

   ```
   SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(archivePath, toDestination:destPath, delegate:self)
   ```
9. Print your path, and you can check there your file will be saved

   ```
   print(zipPath)
   ```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your very comprehensive answer. Fortunately I managed to solve the problem last evening but forgot to mark it on here as so. I wish I could explain exactly how I did it but to be honest I think it was more of a trial and error type of affair. Hope I didn't waste your time by forgetting to say I had fixed my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @JackChamberlain I am also facing the issue as you did. Could you please share your solution.

Comment: I do work with SSZipArchive, it works fine  the unzipping file in the simulator, but same code if run to the device it's not working [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749503/couldn-t-be-opened-because-there-is-no-such-file]

Comment: This code was used for about 2 years ago... now needs to revise accordings to latest iOS

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; check that your source and destination paths don't begin with the `file://` prefix.

More Detail...

I had the same issue, SSZipArchive would run, the `success` variable would print out false, no delegates were called and no debug messages printed from SSZipArchive.

I was running it like this:

```
let sourcePath = sourceURL.absoluteString
let destPath = destURL.absoluteString

print("Source: \(sourcePath)")
print("Dest: \(destPath)")

let success = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: sourcePath, toDestination: destPath, delegate: self)
print("ZipArchive - Success: \(success)")
```

and my log statements were printing out

```
Source: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/longAppIDHere/testApp.app/Bundle1.zip
Dest: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/longAppIDHere/Library/Application Support/testFolder/
ZipArchive - Success: false
```

I changed my path constructors to:

```
let sourcePath = sourceURL.relativePath
let destPath = destURL.relativePath
```

and now SSZipArchive works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone.  [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) or [SwiftyXMLParser](https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser), [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)

```
 //путь к файлу // path to file
    guard let bookPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FileName", ofType: "epub") else {  return }
    //путь к хранилищу телефона // path to storage 
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let bookName = bookPath.lastPathComponent // название файла // name of file
    let bookBasePath = paths.appendingPathComponent(bookName) // ссылка к хранилищу телефона // path to Directory 

    do {
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bookBasePath) {
            SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: bookPath, withContentsOfDirectory:bookBasePath) // создание архива // create zip
            SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: bookPath, toDestination: bookBasePath, delegate: self) // распаковка архива // unzip 
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: bookBasePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil) // создание директории с архивом // create Directory
        }

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bookBasePath){
            // get xml
            let containerPath = "META-INF/container.xml"
            let containerData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: bookBasePath).appendingPathComponent(containerPath), options: .alwaysMapped) // получение xml файла из директории
            print(containerData)
           // parse xml ...
        } else {
            print("file no exists")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```